# iPhone with iOS 6 and Xcode 4.2 issue

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, ios6

I have upgraded my iPhone to iOS 6, however I am currently on Xcode 4.2 (on Snow Leopard). Now I am getting this error message:

> The version of iOS on “xxx xxx” does not match any of the versions of
>   iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK.
>   Please restore the device to a version of the iOS listed below, or
>   update to the latest version of the iOS.

Is it possible to restore my iPhone to older version say 5.1 or some how make my Xcode to support/recognize iOS6?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I followed the following steps, to resolve my issue by making Xcode to support iOS 6:

1.First download Xcode 4.5 .dmg file from [Here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads) (You would need developer account).

2.Then mount this image and use "Show Package Contents" from context menu.

3.Then copy the following folder

> Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/6.1
>   (10A403)

to your mac's following folder (This path may differ from mac to mac based on its version. On `Snow Leopard` you may find the `Developer` folder in `Finder` under `PLACES` section, and probably on `Lion`, you have to right click the `Xcode.app` and have to use `Show Package Contents`):

> Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

4.Similarly copy the iOS 6 SDK folder from following directory:

> Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk

to your mac's following folder

> Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

5.Also copy `version.plist` from `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform` folder to your mac's `Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform` folder.

6.Re-start Xcode and re-connect the device(s).

Bingo !! now Xcode <strike>supports</strike> recognizes iOS6 device(s) and even I am able to run and debug my app (built for older SDKs) on my iPhone with iOS6 (I am not sure about iPhone 6.0 simulator though).

However, answer to `How to restore iPhone to older version say 5.1` is still pending.

Comment: Excellent information. Same technique worked out for Xcode 4.6 to recognize iOS 7.0.2 device

Comment: i have tried this technique for ios 7 but i am getting **Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1** error dont know why please help me out.

Comment: @CrazyProggrammer, I have not tried the approach for iOS 7, I moved to Xcode 5. However I believe this should work. have you followed the procedure for simulator files ? Using this approach, I doubt one would be able to run iOS 7 simulator(s).

Comment: now its working i have also added simulator SDK thats why i am getting this issue. now its perfectly working on my device. thanks.

Comment: many thanks! adding ios6 sdk to xcode4.2 (macmini1,1 - 10.6.8) finally allowed me to submit appication to apple Appstore!

Answer (score 0):

You cant debug iO6 device in Xcode 4.2. **iO6** device debugs only in **Xcode 4.5 (latest one)**. And most importent for **installing Xcode 4.5**, in your machine must have **at least Lion Operating System**.For efficiently debugging of iOS device, You must upgrade your OS.

Comment: But I am able to debug my app (previously build for iOS 5.1) on my iPhone (with iOS 6) in my Xcode 4.2 after following my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem !

Downgrading iOS 6 in your iPhone is not officially supported by Apple anymore :

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4533316?start=0&tstart=0

What works for me was to install Lion in an external HD USB, upgrade Xcode to the latest version and upgrade the Provisioning Profiles in my Apple Developer account for this environment.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade to Xcode 4.5 (and OSX mountain lion). No previous version of Xcode supports iOS 6. You can also check if you can restore your phone using a previous version of iOS by getting the .ipsw file and option-clicking on "restore" button when selecting your device on iTunes.

Comment: I am not able to upgrade to Xcode 4.5 due to mac's old version.

Comment: I also tried to `restore` my iPhone to version 5.1.1 using `.ipsw` method, but no success. Error shown was "This .ipsw file is not compatible".

Comment: You should reconsider your statement `No previous version of Xcode supports iOS 6`. For reference see my answer.