# How to switch from Xcode 4.1 to 4.5 for iOS 6.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I just moved from Xcode 4.1 to 4.5 in order to supporting IOS version 6.0. 
I modified launch image as 640x1136 pixels and Base SDK is iOS 6.0.
The problem is when I launch the app it throws SIGABRT on main.m and I added exception breakpoint to get more information but It gave breakpoint 1.1 on the same line of the implementation.
However I have noticed that I got a new warning with Xcode 4.5. Warning and Code are written below. Thanks for help.

Warning:

```
Semantic Issue: 'CountrySettingsViewController' may not respond to 'initWithTitle'
```

Code:

```
CountrySettingViewController *countrySettingView = [[[CountrySettingViewController alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"selectCountry",@"Select the country title")]retain];
```

Comment: Is there a method in the countrySettingViewController called initWithTitle?

Comment: I don't think you should be calling `retain` on an object you alloc'd and init'd.  Your retain count is 2 after that line.

Comment: ...what CBredlow said, plus: are you aware that alloc+init already retains the object?

Comment: There is initWithTitle Method in the countrySettingViewController and this code was working without warning when it was running on Xcode 4.1. I don't know if I need to do something new for viewController in iOS 6.0. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not yet ready to jump to xcode 4.5.  - because, then a lot of old projects will have to be recompiled e.t.c.

In order to support iphone 5 display, I simply made everything autoresizing, extra checking for iphone 5 display (to set corresponding image),  and added iPhone 5 splash screen image. Compiling from 4.4.1, and on iPhone 5 it will look ok.

I then copy installed application from 5.1. simulator to 6.0 simulator, and launch 6.0 simulator, to check how it will look on iPhone 5 (while I don't yet have any iPhone 5 to test).

Hope that helps.

(I have 4.4.1. sdk and 4.5. sdk installed)

---

But about that error -

is this "initWithTitle" function declared in .h file also?  Or else other classes will not see it (even if it works).

Comment: I don't think that will really work here, since the crash error seems to be caused by a class calling a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Guntis, I am going to try your solution. Thanks

Comment: @CBredlow Probably, but I'm just proposing another way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I sorted out my problem from the following answer in link:
[iPhone with iOS 6 and Xcode 4.2 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621481/iphone-with-ios-6-and-xcode-4-2-issue)