# iOS 7 deployment with Xcode 4.2 or 4.6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have the Xcode version 4.2( can upgrade unto 4.6 ).I want to run ios7 application in my simulator.So I searched on stack overflow and found this.
[iPhone with iOS 6 and Xcode 4.2 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621481/iphone-with-ios-6-and-xcode-4-2-issue)

i have tried this technique for ios 7 but i am getting **Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1** error dont know why please help me out.

**ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/host/libdyld.dylib for architecture i386**

I don't know why m getting this error.Please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have an iOS7 simulator, and be able to build for this version, you have to upgrade to XCode 5.

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is that "to have an iOS 7 simulator, you have to upgrade to Xcode 5".

Comment: my hardware does not support malvaric os so i couldn't upgrade to Xcode 5 so i have to try above technique.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann thanks, answered improved. If you can not upgrade to `XCode 5` you might probably stuck with this problem.

Comment: You don't need Mavericks for Xcode 5, Mountain Lion will suffice

Answer (score 0):

To develop for iOS 7 you need to upgrade to Xcode 5. It's always the best practice is to use the latest tools as suggested by the apple. As per this [link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a) **Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be optimized for iOS 7**

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that libdyld.dylib does not exist on your system. The iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk folder which you have probably copied into your system from a downloaded xcode_5.0.2.dmg or similar contains a symlink to /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib which probably only exists on newer versions of OSX.

However, it looks like one might get around this by using one of the libdyld.dylib files that are in that xcode dmg file. I did the following, which "fixed" the problem for me:

```
cd /usr/lib/system
sudo cp /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib .
```

This is of course a dirty, dirty hack, and if you want to do this the right way, you should upgrade to Xcode 5, as the other commenters have helpfully suggested.